# Carriage returns in comments?

Tags: feature-request

I get the need to separate comments from answers, but I don't get why you can not use paragraphs in the comments. Bring good grammar to comments!! (Please?)

Comment: Why has this received a negative vote? Is the question invalid in some way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think paragraph formating should be allowed in comments.  You shouldn't need it if you are using comments for there intended purpose.  If you need more than 1 paragraph it should be an answer.

Some formatting options are allowed i comments.

- `**text** or __text__ = Bolding = text`
- `*text* or _text_ = Italics = text`
- `'text'= Code Formatting = text`
- `[example](http://example.com "title") Inline links with title and text`
- http://example.com plain old links

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  It took me *forever* to figure out how to do an inline link with text ...

Comment: surely, whether or not a response is determined to be a comment or an answer should be decided by the content, and not grammatical structure or length?

Answer (score 1):

The creators of this [network of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/) are always [cautious about adding features](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/) that might encourage conversation instead of answering questions. *"We don’t want Stack Overflow to turn into a social networking site for chatty cathys, so there’s only so far we will go in supporting pure conversation."* Adding newlines to comments [has been asked before and declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments), and while I understand you (and sometimes want them too, certainly here on meta), I think we should not hope too much for them.

You can find much more discussion on the features of this site and others in the network on the general [Stack Overflow Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: is this site not separate? can we not do things the way this community wants? (not that I am claiming any knowledge of the will of the community)

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: All sites run from the same servers, and the same code. Currently, it is not possible to get server-side customizations for one site. Some sites get [extra features via JavaScript files](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed), but this is only in unusual circumstances. That would not help in this case, since the server strips the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Shift+Enter will give you a carriage return

Comment: Yes it will, but StackExchange will strip those carriage returns so they result is the same, unfortunately.